# VisualSVN with Intellij

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, intellij-14, visualsvn

I'm trying to check out my repository using subversion through Intellij. I've installed tortoisesvn on my computer and I have visualsvn installed on a server. I believe I have everything configured somewhat correctly, but I'm getting a error when checking out my repository. What is the reasoning behind this error I'm getting.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VisualSVN was out of date and needed to be updated to the latest version in which solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE has "C:\Program Files..." recorded somewhere **without quotes**, so it only recognises the portion of the path till the first whitespace character. Perhaps it looks for the svn.exe executable or something like that. So you need to enclose the path in double quotes.

If my assumption above is correct, this looks like a bug in your IDE (it's worth reporting it to IntelliJ developers).

### Update #1

Since the other error is `protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate` I think that IntelliJ doesn’t support modern TLS versions. Check if you are using the latest version. Or [change the TLS/SSL compatibility level to ‘Legacy’](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00195/) in VisualSVN Server.

Comment: I'll send in a ticket to IntelliJ. One thing I noticed is if I turn off interactive mode. I receive the error cannont checkout from svn: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate). A forum on IntelliJ says turn on interactive mode to get around it, but I'm back to where I started.

Comment: Check if TortoiseSVN is up to date and if the svn client used by your IDE is up to date too. If the client is too old, then perhaps upgrading the client will help or [changing the TLS/SSL compatibility level to 'Legacy' will help](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00195/) (this idea comes from the error "protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate" you mentioned).